# how to pick string basing on ID wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table where i have values like

```
CREATE TABLE VALUES (ID INT,VAL VARCHAR(40))
INSERT INTO VALUES (ID,VAL)VALUES (1,'Chemicals(Sulphur4123)'),(2,'Chemicals(Sulphur4123)/RAW')
```

How can i get result set of :

```
ID  Val
1   Sulphur4123
2   Sulphur4123/RAW
```

so far i have tried but with no luck

my code

```
select Substring(val,0,CHARINDEX('/',val))+ right(val,4) from values
```

Comment: may be you can proceed with substring and ccharindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   declare @t table (ID int,value varchar(40))
   insert into @t (ID,value)values (1,'Chemicals(Sulphur4123)'),(2,'Chemicals(Sulphur4123)/RAW')

   select  SUBSTRING(value,
   CHARINDEX('(',value) + 1, 
   CHARINDEX(')',value) - CHARINDEX('(',value) - 1)+
   +reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(value),1,CHARINDEX('/',reverse(value))))
   AS RESULT from @t
```

Comment: this is showing some promise let me try with my table @Mohan111

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your database .User custom function is what you find If your database support it.

```
                    CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS f AS $$ String f(String str) {
return str.substring(str.indexOf("/"));
                   }$$;

SELECT ID,F(VALUE ) FROM VALUES
```

Comment: sql server 2008 R2 @nero

Comment: not a problem above code belongs to which database @nero